# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now. remove or edit

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now. remove or edit

how can we remove or change its text.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a translation file in your theme. That file would live be placed in:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/i18n/en_US.csv

Inside the .csv file, you can change the text like this:

```
 "We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.","What ever text you like"
```

There is a example of the syntax here:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

For more information, you can read up on translation here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: its not working on product page when i am adding product its getting me this error i need to change it i have applied with theme under i18n this folder i have create two sheet en_GB.csv and en_US.csv i also i did smae changes on vendor folder checkout and sell

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/q2FGwGrvM6wnmpEz/gwcc.viewyoursite.co.uk

Comment: "We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.","Minimum order quantity is five pieces."

Comment: this is csv file text